# How to set variable in JSON cookie?

Tags: javascript, json, cookies, js-cookie

I'm using **js.cookie.js** [Github](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) and trying to set a JSON cookie.
In documentation of **js.cookie.js** mentioned that if you want set a JSON cookie you must do like this:

```
Cookies.set('name', { foo: 'bar' });
```

so the cookie data will be like below if you call `Cookies.getJSON('name');`:

```
{ foo: 'bar' }
```

Now my question is how to set `foo` from a javascript variable. I tried this but was not useful:

```
var myVar = 'foo';
Cookies.set('name', { myVar: 'bar' });
```

the result was `{ myVar: 'bar' }` and not `{ foo: 'bar' }`

My JSFIDDLE.COM test: https://jsfiddle.net/nz2ur613/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.onload = Do();
   function Do() {
   var myvar = 'foo';
   var obj = {} ;
   obj[myvar] = 'bar';
   Cookies.set('name', obj);
   alert(Cookies.get('name'));
 }
```

I created an object and then set it to cookie.

Try this one. It will work

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/snuny9om/

Comment: Thanks man! It worked fine.

Comment: Most Welcome !!